# Java toString with 2 array Lists

Tags: java

So basically I have a class, Invoice, that has 2 arrays. One for a list of items, one for a list of prices. I want my toString function, when called, to print the name of the item, left justified, with exactly 15 characters, and then the price of it, with 6 characters and 2 places after the decimal. However, I am not sure what is wrong in my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Invoice {
  private String name;
  private ArrayList<String> items;
  private ArrayList<Double> prices;

  public Invoice(String _name) {
    name = _name;
    items = new ArrayList<String>();
    prices = new ArrayList<Double>();
  }

  public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
  }
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void addItem(String item, double price) {
    items.add(item);
    prices.add(price);
  }

  public double getTotal() {
    double total = 0.0;
    for(double pr : prices) {
      total += pr;
    }
    return total;
  }

  public String toString() {
    String r = "";
    r += "Invoice for ";
    r += name;
    r += "\n";
    for(String item : items) {
      r += "\n";
      r += String.format("%-15.15s", item);         
    }
    for(double price: prices) {
      r += String.format("%6.2f", price);
    }
    return String.format(r);
 }

}
```

I want the output, when I enter input in my test class, to be

```
Toaster         15.95
Smart Phone    327.63
```

However, my output is:

```
Toaster
Smart Phone    15.95327.63
```

Thank you to anyone that can help explain this to me

Comment: you really should be practicing object oriented programming, which would help with your current issue of iterating your items first, THEN iterating the prices of each item after..

Comment: Allow me to suggest creating a`ItemPrice` class that contains two members: `String item` and `Double price`. Then your `Invoice` class will have a single list, namely `ArrayList<ItemPrice> itemsAndTheirPrices`. Make sure class `ItemPrice` has a `toString()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you are printing all of the items first (Toaster and Smart Phone), and then all of the prices, here:

```
for(String item : items) {
  r += "\n";
  r += String.format("%-15.15s", item);         
}
for(double price: prices) {
  r += String.format("%6.2f", price);
}
```

What you really want to do is to print first item, first price, second item, second price etc. So something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  // Handle item
  r += "\n";
  r += String.format("%-15.15s", items[i]);

  // Handle price
  r += String.format("%6.2f", prices[i]);

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I used this and then substituted the array index code for the ArrayList code and it worked perfectly! I think I was overthinking the solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in one of the comments, this is a great opportunity to use Object Oriented Programming principals.  Rather than separate lists of items and prices, you should have a single object that represents an "item", which has both a name and a price:

```
public class InvoiceItem {
    private String name;
    private Double price;

    public InvoiceItem(String name, Double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%-15.15s", name) + String.format("%6.2f\n", price);
    }
}
```

Note that I'm overriding the `toString()` method so that each InvoiceItem knows how to print itself.

Then, in your Invoice class, you can do something like this:

```
public class Invoice {
private String name;
private List<InvoiceItem> items; // <-- use List instead of ArrayList here

public Invoice(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.items = new ArrayList<>();
}

// I'll leave the implementation of the other methods as an exercise for the reader

public String toString() {
    // StringBuilders are great of iteratively constructing Strings
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (InvoiceItem item : items) {
        sb.append(item.toString());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```